# connecting Android to ASP.net MVC Project

Tags: android, asp.net-mvc

i'm trying to connect an android Application to my ASP.NET MVC project ?
is there anyway i can connect it through the localhost without deploying it on a web server ?
Whats the URL i should give it to the android app.

Answer (score 0):

10.0.2.2 is the IP address visible to emulator for localhost on which emulator is running. [Reference](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/devices/emulator.html#emulatornetworking)